# How do I call a method within a Child component from the Parent in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

How do I call a method within a Child component from the Parent in React Native? What I essentially want to do is emulate what `componentDidMount()` does for class components in a functional component.

I've been getting the error "Function components cannot be given refs" and that I may want to use `React.ForwardRef()`.

ps. idk how i would go about reformatting the child observer, pardon the bad formatting

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.load = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
     this.load.current.loadAudio();
  }

 render(){
      latestEP.query = ref => ref.orderBy("id", "desc").limit(1);

     return(
      {latestEP.docs.map(doc => (
       <DashboardItem key={doc.id} doc={doc} ref={this.load} />
       ))}
  )
 }
}

const DashboardItem = observer(({ doc }) => {
 function loadAudio(){
   return console.log("works")}

 return (// stuff that requires loadAudio to run first)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using `useImperativeHandle` hook. Please check this out:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

Wrap `DashItem` in `forwardRef` and implement `useImperativeHandle` hook like below:

```
const DashItem = React.forwardRef(({doc}, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    loadAudio: () => {
      return console.log("works");
    }
  }));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "Function components cannot be given refs" should be self-explanatory: you need to change `DashItem` to be a class component instead of a functional component.

Comment: I was leaving out some extra info my bad, edited question for clarity